# how does Rollback works with nested functions in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

It is known that if Transactions encounter an error it rollbacks.

But what happens when we have the following situation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
    perform B();
    perform C();
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE    

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION C()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
    insert into table_C(pk_a,ab,ac)
    select id,name,phone
    from users
    where....
    perform E();

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

what happens when I call `A()` and `C()` has `'duplicate key error'` on `INSERT` to `table_C` ? Will it rollback only `C()`? Or `A()` with all it's sub calls and changes will rollback as well?

The rollback mechanism is defined per transactions... if I understood correctly transactions is a set of SQL queries. So how many transactions I have here? Is `PostgreSQL` choose the number of transactions by itself? each function is a transaction on its own?

Comment: You only have a single transaction (assuming no autocommit). Each function call is "just" a SQL statement.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to save all the data of the query in C if it's rolledback?

Comment: @John No. For that you'd need autonomous commit, which PostgreSQL doesn't support. Read about subtransactions, and read the plpgsql error handling section including the part about begin ... except .